# Can I speed up a large JDBC query with Futures?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table with millions of rows. One of the columns is a timestamp and I need to query rows with time greater than x and less than y. Since I am getting hundreds of thousands of rows back, the query is taking a long time even though I indexed it.

My plan is to use a list of Futures to each make a query over a small time interval concurrently and then I will aggregate the results after.

Should I expect the large speedup I'm hoping for? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Please edit your question to add `explain analyze` output

Comment: You will need to multi thread yourself as JDBC has no async API. You could use futures to combine the results of those threads. However doing parallelisation should be a service provider by your database. Doing it hand made might not speed up the result at all. Try to use aggregation statements inside the DB instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on where you're bottlenecked. If it's on network I/O it won't help significantly.

If it's disk I/O, it might help a bit, since it'll effectively parallelize the query. But only if your DB server benefits significantly from I/O parallelization. It's possible that you won't see much benefit, so test it by manually dispatching a bunch of queries simultaneously and timing it to see before you bother reworking your code.

Make sure you're doing forward index scans though - see `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`; you'll get less benefit if you're doing backward index scans.

TL;DR: Benchmark and see.